# Semantic UI image automatically scaling

Tags: css, semantic-ui

so I have a problem, that I believe has to do with semantic UI handling of cards

I have a html heirarchy like of using

```
<div class='carousel ui container cards'>
  <div class='card'>
    <div class='image'>
      <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50'>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='description'>fdjsnajfdnsjk fjsanskjfn</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the image that I have for the card is 50px x 50px however semantic UI seems to upscale the image to 290px x 290px. what I am wondering is there a way to override this? or should I just use a different view component?

Comment: seems img style is made flexible with width:100%; Remove that!

Comment: Did you try defining the width and height of the image like so? `<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/50x50' width='50px' height='50px'>`

Comment: `.ui.cards>.card>.image>img` is setting width to 100%